# Получить список устройств по гуид-классу

Tags: c#

Как получить список usb устройств по гуид классу  что бы работать с ним как с файлом например(как в с++)? LibUsb, DotNetUsb не предлагать

Comment: Предлагаю SetupAPI :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  может есть ссылочка на ресурс или какой-то пример?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples в этом репозитории есть usbview. Она делает почти все что можно с USB